# Simulação de Monte Carlo para distribuição t de student no R

Tags: r

Eu tenho o seguinte conjunto de dados:

```
A = c(14, 11, 18,7,12,11,6)
B = c(14,23,17,16,15,20,16)
```

Gostaria de fazer uma simulação de diversas amostras com distribuição t de student dos dois grupos para comparar quantas vezes a amostra B é em média maior do que a A.

Eu tentei o seguinte código:

```
n<- 100000
amostra_A <- rt (n, mean(A),sd(A))
amostra_B <- rt (n, mean(B), sd(B))
p.b_superior <- sum(amostra_B > amostra_A)/n
```

O resultado deu que a amostra B seria maior somente 28% das vezes, o que não faz sentido, tendo em vista que os valores de B são maiores.

Tentei a modificação para uma distribuição normal e os valores ficaram mais próximos do esperado:

```
n<- 100000
amostra_A <- rnorm (n, mean(A),sd(A))
amostra_B <- rnorm (n, mean(B), sd(B))
p.b_superior <- sum(amostra_B > amostra_A)/n
```

Nesse caso, a amostra B aparece maior em 87,5% das vezes.

Entretanto, quando faço o t.test para as duas amostras, tenho um p-valor de 1%, o que indica que existe significância estatística para afirmar que as duas amostras são diferentes.

Pelo que li, a simulação de Monte Carlo chegaria a valores pŕóximos do p-valor, o que não ocorreu nem na simulação com uma normal e menos ainda na simulação com a distribuição t-student.

Imagino que no caso da distribuição t-student, eu esteja fazendo alguma coisa errada.

Comment: Os códigos `amostra_A <- rt(n, mean(A),sd(A))` e `amostra_B <- rt(n, mean(B), sd(B))` não fazem sentido para mim. De acordo com a documentação da função `rt`, o comando `rt (n, mean(A), sd(A))` significa que serão geradas `n` amostras independente de uma t de Student com graus de liberdade iguais a `mean(A)` e parâmetro de não-centralidade igual a `sd(A)`. Isso está correto?

Comment: Como o Marcus colocou, a função rt não utiliza informações de média e variância. rt(n, df, ncp) // df - degrees of freedom  // ncp - non-centrality parameter δ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como foi mencionado nos comentários da questão original, a função `rt` depende de três parâmetros, tamanho da série (`n`), graus de liberdade (`df`) e não centralidade (`ncp`). Se você tivesse uma amostra maior de dados poderia usar alguma função para estimar esses parâmetros, como `fGarch::stdFit()`.

No seu caso, pode usar a função `rt` para gerar uma distribuição com média zero, basta não definir o parâmetro `ncp`, e depois somar a média que desejar à série gerada. Para incorporar a variância (`varx`) pode usar a relação entre esta é os graus de liberdade (`df`): `varx = df/(df-2)`. Dessa forma pode obter o valor do `df` para usar como parâmetro.

```
Varx =1.02  # valor definido para replicar aproximadamente a distribuição dos seus dados
n<- 100000
set.seed(432)
amostra_A <- rt (n, 2*Varx/(Varx-1))+mean(A)
amostra_B <- rt (n, 2*Varx/(Varx-1))+mean(B)
(p.b_superior <- sum(amostra_B > amostra_A)/n)
sapply(list(amostra_A , amostra_B),summary)

# para ggplot
data <- rbind(data.frame(valor=amostra_A,amostra="Amostra A"),
                    data.frame(valor=amostra_B,amostra="Amostra B"))
ggplot(data, aes(valor, fill = amostra)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
```

> ```
> > (p.b_superior <- sum(amostra_B > amostra_A)/n)
> [1] 0.99995
> > sapply(list(amostra_A , amostra_B),summary)
>              [,1]     [,2]
> Min.     6.375751 12.88123
> 1st Qu. 10.604696 16.59484
> Median  11.291627 17.27721
> Mean    11.284271 17.27938
> 3rd Qu. 11.961175 17.96108
> Max.    16.251446 22.83622
> ```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.

Só não entendi como vc chegou ao valor de Varx =1.02 . Poderia me esclarecer?

Comment: A fórmula é uma aproximação para o caso de uma série aleatória da distribuição t  com média zero. O valor foi escolhido por tentativa e erro, procurando gerar e replicar a forma da distribuição de seus dados amostrais.